# Getting previous call duration instead of Last call Duration in android?

Tags: android

I am creating an application that disconnects calls programatically based on some rule!. What i am getting trouble is i am trying to get the call duration of last call after disconnecting the phone! 
But the issue is the duration i am getting is previous call duration and not the disconnected call!

my Code is:

```
public void disconnect(){
    disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
    calldisconnected();
    WhitelistDAO whiteListDao1 = new WhitelistDAO(context);
    String dura = LastCall();
    if (dura.equals("0")) {
        int dbTime = Integer.parseInt(whiteListDao1.getLimit(finalNumber));
        whiteListDao1.updateLimit(String.valueOf(dbTime), finalNumber);
    } else {
        whiteListDao1.updateLimit("0", finalNumber);
    }
}


public String LastCall() {
        String callDura = "0";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Uri contacts = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return null;
        }
        Cursor managedCursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                contacts, null, null, null, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE+ " DESC limit 1;");
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER );
        int duration1 = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        if( managedCursor.moveToFirst() == true ) {
            String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
            callDura = managedCursor.getString( duration1 );
            String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            String callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate)).toString();
            String dir = null;
            Log.e("DUR","\nPhone Number:--- "+phNumber +" \nCall duration in sec :--- "+callDura +" \nCall Date in sec :--- "+callDayTime );
        }
        managedCursor.close();
        return callDura;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should solve it!
Run the function in handler with a 1 second delay! Then you will get the correct last call duration and not the previous call duration. I think android cannot get the last call details immediately after discoonection! May be it takes a second delay for insertion in database!

Like:

```
 private Handler handler = new Handler();
    public void disconnect(){
        disconnectPhoneItelephony(context);
        calldisconnected();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            WhitelistDAO whiteListDao1 = new WhitelistDAO(context);
            String dura = LastCall();
            if (dura.equals("0")) {
                int dbTime = Integer.parseInt(whiteListDao1.getLimit(finalNumber));
                whiteListDao1.updateLimit(String.valueOf(dbTime), finalNumber);
            } else {
                whiteListDao1.updateLimit("0", finalNumber);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);

    }
```

Comment: My Pleasure! Happy coding